# Display Map (Google API V2) Only on a Specific Area Of Screen

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout

I want to show the map in the middle of the screen and want to show the header and footer separately which contains the options or menu buttons. Can Any one please tell me how can i set my layout so it will be best fit on every device. My current layout code is this. 
`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<fragment
android:id="@+id/map"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/setup_macroSavebtn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Ride Now"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/setup_macroCancelbtn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Ride Later"/>         
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>`
```

Comment: Use Linear layout as container, set the height of header and footer to wrap content, set the height of map to 0dp, and weight to 1.

Comment: Header and footer will be linear or relative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although pasting code is seriously not the way to answer, so I will advice you to use *weights* for the map, and set the header and footer height to `wrap_content`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button02"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Ride Now" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button01"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Ride Later" />
</LinearLayout>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/setup_macroSavebtn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Ride Now" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/setup_macroCancelbtn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Ride Later" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks Alot Twntee, It works for me, Rest I'll modify my self, Now I got the idea what I've to do here